# Mysql socket is missing in my homestead docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, laravel-4

I have this issue with my app

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through
>   socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'(2)

I'm using 2 docker containers to host my laravel 4.2 (I think :o) from this [build](https://hub.docker.com/r/shincoder/homestead/builds/byytcq8f7ybuhbxb98penc9/)

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
web:
image: shincoder/homestead:php5.6
restart: always
ports:
    - "8000:80" # web
    - "2222:22" # ssh
    - "35729:35729" # live reload
    - "9876:9876" # karma server
volumes:
    - ~/.composer:/home/homestead/.composer # composer caching
    - ~/.gitconfig:/home/homestead/.gitconfig # Git configuration ( access alias && config )
    - ~/.ssh:/home/homestead/.ssh # Ssh keys for easy deployment inside the container
    - ~/apps:/apps # all apps
    - ~/apps/volumes/nginx/sites-available:/etc/nginx/sites-available # nginx sites ( in case you recreate the container )
    - ~/apps/volumes/nginx/sites-enabled:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled # nginx sites ( in case you recreate the container )
links:
    - mariadb
mariadb:
    image: tutum/mariadb
    restart: always
    ports:
        - "33060:3306"
    environment:
        MARIADB_USER: admin # cannot be changed ( for info. only )
        MARIADB_PASS: root
    volumes:
        - ~/apps/volumes/mysql:/var/lib/mysql # database files
```

the first one is homesteaddocker_web_1 with php5.6 and the second one homesteaddocker_mariadb_1.
I've searched for the mysql socket in homesteaddocker_web_1 and its not there but I've found it in the second container (homesteaddocker_mariadb_1)

So how can I fix this please.

Answer (score 0):

Docker containers are networked with a bridge.

For one container to talk to another, you need to link them:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/

If your container needs to access network ressources on your local network, you may want to use `--network='host'` in your docker run command.

Comment: I'm even more confused, I updated my question with the docker-compose file.

Comment: I thought you were trying to access a DB that is running on your host. So, my bad. 
Now, what does your connection string look like? You should not be exposing the mariadb port (unless you need it from outside) and you should be connecting to mariadb:3306

Comment: @MrEI can access my db through mysql workbench with these credentials (host: 127.0.0.1, port:33060, username and password)  and it works fine. its my laravel app who Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket.

Comment: try getting into the container and see if you can ping / reach the other container.

Comment: `docker exec -it <container_id> /bin/sh`